# Is it possible to send mobile notifications at the moment when plugging in the charger?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mobile, notifications

I am trying to send notifications every time I connect my mobile with the charger. So my question is, whether this is possible in Unity and if it is, how can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is an internal event that specifies when the user stops and starts charging their phone, but there is a field you can access to check it at any point called [`SystemInfo.batteryStatus`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BatteryStatus.Charging.html). If you store the previous state and whenever this state is altered, you can fire a notification immediately instead of waiting to store it using Unity's [`Notification System Package`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.notifications@1.4/manual/index.html). Depending on if you are on iOS / Android, sending a notification is slightly different.

```
private BatteryStatus isBatteryCharging = BatteryStatus.Unknown;

private void Update()
{
    if(SystemInfo.batteryStatus != isBatteryCharging)
    {
        // update our current state
        isBatteryCharging = SystemInfo.batteryStatus;
        
        // now handle if we are charging
        if(isBatteryCharging == BatteryStatus.Charging)
            SendNotification();
    }
}

private void SendNotification()
{
    // notification code here you can find on the Unity Notification Package Docs   
}
```

I will not include the code for notifications as you did not specify if you want an OS-specific solution or cross OS-specific solution. Everything should be on the link I posted from Unity Tutorials if you need it.